# Exception : Invalid Image Data in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a problem with showing images from the internet in flutter.
basically the problem is that when i use an image with the http protocol , it seems like flutter can't decode it

My Code :

```
Image.network('http://bi3li.rf.gd/acunetix-logo.png');
```

please help !

I have tried to return images from a php file with header type image/jpeg ,
but I still have the same problem .

Comment: Because that URL leads to 404 error page. This resource either must be public or have authentication added

Comment: no , browser show it normally

Comment: How is this related to PHP?

Comment: _"no , browser show it normally"_ - Not when we test that link. It leads to, as already pointed out, a 404 page.

Comment: your URL link leads to a 404 error page
check it yourself in private windows

Comment: @MEDX Most likely it's shown for you, because you have active session. Open it in incognito tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the probelm is solved by just changing the upload api,
cuz my hosting retrun an text/html content even f i try to return an image , that doesnt work so .. yes !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).